# how to define a case class for variable length DataFrame in scala?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a  very large text file with variable length, the first ,5th and last columns are  of interested to do a RDD action

$cat rdd.txt

```
chr1    1    0.42235 0.01501 10001   110000
chr1    2    0.41104 0.01254 60001   160000
chr1    3    0.42826 0.00282 110001  177417  227418  260000
chr1    4    0.4151  0.00288 160001  177417  227418  267719  317720  360000
chr1    5    0.39534 0.00166 260001  267719  317720  410000
scala> sc.version
res0: String = 2.0.1


scala> case class Chrom(name: String, value: Long, value: Long   ????)
```

how to model a case class to access the first, 5th and last column?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
case class Chrom(name: String, value: Long *)
```

but it is only a syntactic sugar for having a sequence (array) column:

```
Seq(Chrom("a",  1, 2, 3)).toDF.as[Chrom]
```